# as HTMLCanvasElement not Working on Canvas

Tags: javascript, html, typescript, canvas

This code **works!** but makes warning

> Argument type HTMLElement is not assignable to parameter type CanvasImageSource

```
function flipImage() {
            const img = document.getElementById("img_v");
            const ctx = img.getContext('2d');
            ctx.setTransform(1,0,0,-1,0,img.height);
            ctx.scale(-1, 1);
            ctx.drawImage(img, -img.width, 0);
        }

<canvas id="img_v"></canvas>
```

So, I fixed but both codes **not working!**

*Warning have been removed*

```
const img = document.getElementById("img_v") as HTMLCanvasElement;
const img = document.getElementById("img_v") as HTMLImageElement;
```

How do I fix it?

Comment: Is this Typescript? If so, please include that as a tag.

Comment: It is Javascript on Html @DBS

Comment: I don't believe `as` is a keyword in vanilla JS, nor are the types you are talking about.

Comment: Where do these warnings come from? Sounds like it's just your IDE assuming you are writing in TypeScript when it should be configured to plain js.

Answer (score 0):

I presume this is in JavaScript and not TypeScript. Your second example uses TypeScript feature not available in simple JavaScript (`as HTMLCanvasElement`).

To get rid of the warning in JavaScript (and also provide better suggestions based on types), you have to first check if the element returned by `getElementById()` is of the correct type (in your case `HTMLCanvasElement`).

So you need to change your function to look like this:

```js
function flipImage() {
  const img = document.getElementById("img_v");
  if (img instanceof HTMLCanvasElement) {
    const ctx = img.getContext('2d');

    // Draw sample image just so we know the example is working
    const image = new Image(50, 50);
    image.src = 'https://i1.sndcdn.com/artworks-YBYtb3jTuIvHpI84-J01Dng-t300x300.jpg';
    ctx.drawImage(image, 0, 0);

    // Continue from here
    ctx.setTransform(1, 0, 0, -1, 0, img.height);
    ctx.scale(-1, 1);
    ctx.drawImage(img, -img.width, 0);
  }
}

flipImage();
```

```html
<canvas id="img_v"></canvas>
```

This should get rid of the warning you're seeing and also provide better suggestions for the `ctx` object.